# Yii2 not maintained?

Tags: yii

Craft is based on the PHP framework Yii2.
I heard that this framework is less and less maintained.
And yes, it seems to be the case if you go on contributor page :
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/graphs/contributors

Question to @pixeltonic : how do you think you will you manage it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It’s still maintained. 2.0.48 is currently [in development](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/milestone/70), and 2.2 is [being planned](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/discussions/19831) as well.

That said, the core maintainers’ focus has shifted to Yii 3, which is a drastic departure from Yii 2, and would require significant effort for us to switch to once it’s stable. So we are not expecting we will stick with Yii in the long run, and plan on porting Craft to Laravel/Symfony. We’ll have more to say about that post-Craft 5.0.

Comment: Laravel port, lessgo! I just had chills.

Comment: So cool to switch on Laravel or Symfony :)